# Is there a way to check if an external program is running from Katalon Studio?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, test-automation-framework, katalon

My application has a print document option that opens the pdf reader.

Is there a way to check if the pdf reader is running from **Katalon**?

Comment: Not sure why someone has voted to close as it's primarily opinion based... where's the opinion here? Is there a way to check if the .pdf reader is running from Katalon Studio or not? It sounds pretty black and white to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking if the process is running by using a CustomKeyword ?

**In your Keyword:**

```
@Keyword
boolean processIsRunning(String processName) {

    def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
    def cmd = 'tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ' + processName + '"'
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitForOrKill(1000)

    if(sout.indexOf(processName) < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

**In your TestCase (Script mode):**

```
boolean process = CustomKeywords.'main.CheckProcess.processIsRunning'('explorer.exe')

if (process)
   KeywordUtil.markPassed("Process is running")
else
   KeywordUtil.markFailed("Process not running, test failed")
```